# The proof of the integral test using the contradiction method.

Tags: improper-integrals, alternative-proof

I am currently writing a short note about the proof techniques. I found a random theorem and wanted to write a proof by contradiction as an example. The theorem says

> The integral $\int_{1}^{\infty}1/x^{p}\,\mathrm{d}x$ converges if and
>   only if $p>1$.

This means that I have to prove that

$\impliedby:$ If $p>1$, then $\int_{1}^{\infty}1/x^{p}\,\mathrm{d}x$ converges, and

$\implies$: If $p\leq 1$, then $\int_{1}^{\infty}1/x^{p}\,\mathrm{d}x$ diverges.

Proving the first case is easy. The second case is contraposed implication, which is also easy to prove --- but I want to prove it by contradiction with this implication. Should I say,

(i) Assume that there exists a $p>1$ such that $\int_{1}^{\infty}1/x^{p}\,\mathrm{d}x$ diverges, or

(ii) Assume that there exists a $p\leq 1$ such that $\int_{1}^{\infty}1/x^{p}\,\mathrm{d}x$ converges?

If (ii) is correct, then the proof would be too superfluous. Is there a better way to prove it by contradiction (with or without this implication)?

Comment: (ii) is correct. The only possible use for a proof by contradiction here is that you can prove the result for $p=1$ directly, and then prove that if it converged for some $p\lt 1$, it would converge for $p=1$.

Comment: Do you have to use this theorem? Proving the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ is the classic contradiction proof.